# how many different subnets can there be for an ip address block that begins with 172.64 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.224?

Tags: networking, subnet

I don't want the answer so much as I have no idea how to **find** the answer. Can anybody help me with this?

It's a question from homework in a data networking course.

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains it all. You must know the size of the subnets or how many hosts for each subnet in order to calculate how many subnets.

Comment: The accepted answer has been obsolete for 26 years.

Comment: *ip address block that begins with 172.64* is uniquely interpreted as 172.64.0.0/16. *subnet mask of 255.255.255.224* is /27. So the subnets count is 2^(27-16) = 2^11 = 2048.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=subnet+calculator+ip+block
2. http://www.subnet-calculator.com/
3. Class B network
4. IP: 172.64.0.1
5. Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.224
6. Maximum Subnets: 2048

[image: subnet calculator]

7. Don't forget to show your work.

Comment: It's my browser's default search engine?

Comment: Network classes are dead (please, let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (26 years ago!) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking does not use classes. Your answer is obsolete.

Comment: How would you interpret 172.64/27?

Comment: *How would you interpret 172.64/27?* No way. Whereas *ip address block that begins with 172.64* is uniquely interpreted as 172.64.0.0/16.

Comment: @Akina: No, usually 172.64/27 is just interpreted as 172.64.0.0/27 (though omitting the zeroes for a non-/16 is particularly rare). It does not matter what numbers the address block begins with – it only ever was "uniquely /16" in a class-based system, and as Ron noted, that hasn't been correct for decades.

Comment: @grawity *usually 172.64/27 is just interpreted as 172.64.0.0/27* Usually. But no guarantee...